# Need easy way out for change detection in dataset programatically c#

Tags: c#

what is the easiest way to find out those data which has been changed in dataset. i need point out programatically those data which has been modified.

Comment: Let's start with some basics. How does the data change? Is it edited by the user in a grid? Is it refreshed from a DB and already changed before bound to the UI? Some details wouldn't hurt...

Comment: @Closers: why is this "not a real question"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DataSet changes = ds.GetChanges();
```

This will return a dataset with all the changes since the last time Accept or reject was called on the dataset.

You can also apply rowstatefilters i.e. if you want to see only those rows that have been modified:

```
DataSet changes = ds.GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified);
```

Or Added:

```
DataSet changes = ds.GetChanges(DataRowState.Added);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use GetChanges method on the DataSet object as described at : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4ey25we.aspx